# How can declaration a couple of two dimensional array and pointer to it, in header file and define both in cpp file

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I declared a 2D array and a pointer to it in the header file and defined them in the .cpp file as follows.
my header file:

```
extern byte  GeneralBitmap[][Heigth];
extern byte (*GeneralBitmap_ptr)[][Heigth];
```

and my cpp file:

```
 byte  GeneralBitmap[Width][Heigth];
 byte (*GeneralBitmap_ptr)[Width][Heigth] = &GeneralBitmap;
```

But the compiler returns this error:

```
error: conflicting declaration 'byte (* GeneralBitmap_ptr)[320][4]' byte (*GeneralBitmap_ptr)[Width][Heigth] = &GeneralBitmap;
```

Please help me.

Comment: You forgot to include `Width` in the declaration in the header. Also note that arrays are stored in [row major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) so it's common to talk about `[Height][Width]`, `[Rows][Columns]`, `[Y][X]` etc ...

Comment: Thank you.Change "extern byte (*GeneralBitmap_ptr)[][Heigth];" to "extern byte (*GeneralBitmap_ptr)[Width][Heigth];" solve my problem. But i can't understand why it is diffrent for  variable and pointer.